How can i edit this Bootstrap5 dopdown menu?
I need to make the dropdown menu as this page without the content, that occupies all the width of the page. I also need to make all the "lorem" links of the menu central in the navbar. I'm not able to edit bootstrap classes so I can't make this. How can I fix that? (please open it in full page, and i don't know why with the code snipped the hover menu doesn't work)


.navbar-nav {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: space-between;
      align-items: center;
    }

    .navbar a:hover {
      text-decoration: underline;
    }

    .navbar-nav {
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: space-between;
    }

    .dropdown-menu {
      font-size: 0.8rem;
      left: 0;
      border: none;
      text-align: center;
      position: absolute;
      border-radius: 0;
      box-shadow: 0 10px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
      display: grid;
      grid-template-columns: auto auto auto auto auto;
      visibility: hidden;
      min-width: 100%;
      z-index: 999;
    }

    .dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu {
      visibility: visible;
    }

    .dropdown-menu.show {
      display: flex;
    }

    .dropdown-menu a:hover {
      color: darkgrey;
      text-decoration: none;
    }

    .dropdown-menu li:first-child a {
      color: darkgrey;
      padding: 20px 0;
    }
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-QWTKZyjpPEjISv5WaRU9OFeRpok6YctnYmDr5pNlyT2bRjXh0JMhjY6hW+ALEwIH" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-C6RzsynM9kWDrMNeT87bh95OGNyZPhcTNXj1NW7RuBCsyN/o0jlpcV8Qyq46cDfL" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                    </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
          <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
              <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">Lorem</a>
              <div class="dropdown-menu">

                <ul>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                </ul>
                <ul>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                </ul>
                <ul>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                </ul>
                <ul>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                </ul>
                <ul>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
              <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">Lorem</a>
              <div class="dropdown-menu">
                <ul>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                </ul>
                <ul>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                </ul>
                <ul>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                </ul>
                <ul>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                </ul>
                <ul>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </li>

            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
              <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">Lorem</a>
              <div class="dropdown-menu">
                <ul>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                </ul>
                <ul>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                </ul>
                <ul>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                </ul>
                <ul>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                </ul>
                <ul>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
              <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">Lorem</a>
              <div class="dropdown-menu">
                <ul>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                </ul>
                <ul>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                </ul>
                <ul>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                </ul>
                <ul>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                </ul>
                <ul>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
              <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">Lorem</a>
              <div class="dropdown-menu">
                <ul>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                </ul>
                <ul>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                </ul>
                <ul>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                </ul>
                <ul>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                </ul>
                <ul>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
              <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">Lorem</a>
              <div class="dropdown-menu">
                <ul>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                </ul>
                <ul>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                </ul>
                <ul>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                </ul>
                <ul>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                </ul>
                <ul>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>




To center the links, remove the me-auto class from the ul, and add class justify-content-center to #navbarSupportedContent

@CBroe okay thanks, and to make all the links display on all the width? like as justify-content: space-around (that is not working)

You can add margin: 0 auto; to your .navbar-nav. That will apply equal sized margins on both sides of your element, making it centered horizontally.


.navbar-nav {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: space-between;
      align-items: center;
    }

    .navbar a:hover {
      text-decoration: underline;
    }

    .navbar-nav {
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: space-between;
      margin: 0 auto;
    }

    .dropdown-menu {
      font-size: 0.8rem;
      left: 0;
      border: none;
      text-align: center;
      position: absolute;
      border-radius: 0;
      box-shadow: 0 10px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
      display: grid;
      grid-template-columns: auto auto auto auto auto;
      visibility: hidden;
      min-width: 100%;
      z-index: 999;
    }

    .dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu {
      visibility: visible;
    }

    .dropdown-menu.show {
      display: flex;
    }

    .dropdown-menu a:hover {
      color: darkgrey;
      text-decoration: none;
    }

    .dropdown-menu li:first-child a {
      color: darkgrey;
      padding: 20px 0;
    }
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-QWTKZyjpPEjISv5WaRU9OFeRpok6YctnYmDr5pNlyT2bRjXh0JMhjY6hW+ALEwIH" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.11.8/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-I7E8VVD/ismYTF4hNIPjVp/Zjvgyol6VFvRkX/vR+Vc4jQkC+hVqc2pM8ODewa9r" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                    </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
          <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
              <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">Lorem</a>
              <div class="dropdown-menu">

                <ul>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                </ul>
                <ul>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                </ul>
                <ul>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                </ul>
                <ul>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                </ul>
                <ul>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
              <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">Lorem</a>
              <div class="dropdown-menu">
                <ul>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                </ul>
                <ul>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                </ul>
                <ul>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                </ul>
                <ul>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                </ul>
                <ul>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </li>

            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
              <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">Lorem</a>
              <div class="dropdown-menu">
                <ul>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                </ul>
                <ul>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                </ul>
                <ul>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                </ul>
                <ul>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                </ul>
                <ul>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
              <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">Lorem</a>
              <div class="dropdown-menu">
                <ul>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                </ul>
                <ul>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                </ul>
                <ul>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                </ul>
                <ul>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                </ul>
                <ul>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
              <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">Lorem</a>
              <div class="dropdown-menu">
                <ul>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                </ul>
                <ul>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                </ul>
                <ul>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                </ul>
                <ul>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                </ul>
                <ul>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
              <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">Lorem</a>
              <div class="dropdown-menu">
                <ul>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                </ul>
                <ul>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                </ul>
                <ul>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                </ul>
                <ul>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                </ul>
                <ul>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>




Thanks, it's working. and to make all the links display on all the width? like as justify-content: space-around (that is not working)

@FedericoMonetti apply width: 100%; to the element, and the links will spread out. Recommend that you use a max width for this also, for really large screens.

@Yogi I can run the code snippet without issues. Are you sure you're not just stuck in responsive mode, because you didn't open it in full page?

how can i make the dropdown menu with a with of 100% of the page? As the page i linked
